How can one hide the seamline caused by the wrapping of a function to a sphere?
I have data2  of the type data2 = {{theta_1, phi_1, value_1},{theta_2, phi_2, value_2},{theta_3, phi_3, value_3},.....,{theta_n, phi_n, value_n}},
where:

theta is a polar angle (in degrees) and ranges from 0 to 180 degrees
phi is an azimuthal angle (also in degrees) and ranges from 0 to 360 degrees
value is a number ranging between 0 and 1.

What I do is wrap data2 onto a unit sphere as follows and I generate the following plot:

As you can see from the plot, a seam line appears that runs from the north to the south pole. It is important that I can generate the latitude lines the way they appear on the plot. It would be great if that seamline was not present. Is there a way to make this seamline disappear?
Here is the Mathematica code I used to generate the above plot.
(*Define the interpolating function*)
interpf = Interpolation[{{N[#[[1]]] Degree, N[#[[2]]] Degree}, N[#[[3]]]} & /@data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];


Map = SphericalPlot3D[
  3, {\[Theta], 0.0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0.0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
    Module[{val = interpf[\[Theta], \[Phi]]}, 
     If[val < 0.1, {ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][val], 
       Opacity[0]}, {ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][val], 
       Opacity[1]}]]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
     interpf[\[Theta], \[Phi]]]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 10]], 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, Background -> White, 
  ImageSize -> 300];



Add BoundaryStyle -> None.

You are a legend, azerbajdzan! Thank you, thank you, thank you!
